# Summability for bounded sequences

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, summation-method

I was wondering if there is a characterization for those double sequences $\{b_{n,j}\in \mathbb{C}~\vert~n\in \mathbb{N},~j\in \{0,...,n\}\}$ such that for all **bounded** sequences $s_j\in \mathbb{C}$, we have that
$$\sigma_n =\sum_{j=0}^n b_{n,j}s_j$$
converges?

Note I do not ask that for if $s_j\rightarrow s$, then $\sigma_j\rightarrow s$, like in usual summability methods.

Some thoughts:
In functional analysis language, I am basically embedding $c_{00}$ in $ba = (\ell^\infty)^*$ and asking how weak*-convergence of sequences behaves. Maybe this point of view could come in useful.

Comment: $\sum_{j=0}^n b_{n,j}s_j$ is just a finite sum, so obviously converges. Do you mean to ask about $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sigma_n$ ? Or, are you asking if the *sequence* of the $\sigma_n$ converges?

Comment: When does the sequence of the $\sigma_n$ converge.